# How to analyze a C++ header file with a clang tool?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I have seen the examples in clang/tools/, and even built a few simple tools myself.
But all of them work on source files.
For example, I am not sure if I can use clang-check on a header file.

How do I write a clang tool that will allow me to read a header file and ..say.. print the names of all the top level declarations?
This is easy for a source file but I can not figure out how to handle headers.

Comment: Include it into an empty or trivial source file?

Answer (score 1):

Just feed the header file into the tool? The tools also have string-y interface so you can read the file in and pass its contents that way, so the tool doesn't even know what extension the original file came from.

Comment: Turns out is was parsing C for .h files and I got freaked out by errors like "no type called namespace". -xc++ fixed it

Comment: You can also make the extension .hh and clang will know to parse this as a C++ header file.